# bsd background application does not return immediately

Tags: background, return, bsd

I am running background application on freebsd, every time when I close the application, have to press return to see the the application has finished. Sth like

```
$ emacs &
[5] 24515
$ ## close emacs & press return
[5]+  Done                    emacs
```

I am using bash here.

On other system, I was able to see the background application return immediately after I close it.

How can I get that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try `set -o notify` or `set -b` to enable asynchronous job notification.

This is not enabled by default in modern shells because it messes up your display, or rather, the command line you’re currently typing.